# How do I easily format replies to mailing lists from Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mailing-lists

I occasionally participate in mailing list conversations such as the [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/) list.

When I get a reply, I see that lines have a varied number of '>' characters prepended:

```
>
> I see a problem when I do X
>

Does this mean you do not see the problem when you do Y?
Please try Z before you do X and let us know what happens.
```

So, I need to answer this. So I do a "reply all", and edit the message.\ to look like this:

```
>>
>> I see a problem when I do X
>>

>Does this mean you do not see the problem when you do Y?

No, I do not see the problem when I do Y.

>Please try Z before you do X and let us know what happens.

When I do Z first, the problem goes away, thanks!
```

My email client is Outlook 2010 (the Professional Plus variant) . Is there an easy way to automatically prepend the '>' characters to each line the original message when I reply?

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: Version is Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

We can choose "Prefix each line of the original message"

1. Click the File > Options > Mail.
2. Under Replies and forwards, for When replying to a message or When forwarding a message do the
   following:

[image]

Similiar thread I found: [Replying to an e-mail adds ">New e-mail starts here" in every line?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/079a316e-80fd-4dbc-885d-1dd0dba020ed/replying-to-an-email-adds-new-email-starts-here-in-every-line?forum=outlook)